# How to make a swirl-like model?

Tags: modeling

[image]

Does anyone know how I could make a similar "stripes/swirl" model (the orange one around the yellow ball) like in the picture? I've been thinking about making several spirals, but it wouldn't be as irregular as in the picture.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to get pretty close procedurally, I started with an emissive center sphere with another sphere scaled up slightly.

[image]

I'm using a voronoi texture into a color ramp set to constant so that we get a hard cutoff.  We'll feed this output into the alpha input of the principled shader to punch holes in the mesh.  You can experiment with different types of noise here.

[image]

The rest of the manipulation will happen with the coordinate space.

We're rotating the coordinate space along the z axis, scaling it quite a lot, and then feeding it into the voronoi texture.  With the right gradient you should be able to rotate more as you get closer to the center.

[image]

If you don't care whether a seam is present, we can abuse the UV sphere's premade UV map and get much closer to your reference very easily.  We can move the texture over in the X direction as we go from top to bottom.

[image]

There's a much better convergence at the top, here, but there is a seam present on one side.

[image]

The equivalent of this node group is going into the UV editor with proportional edit set to linear and moving the top row of verts along X.

[image]

Lastly, to capture the bumpy nature of the reference, we can add a couple of subdivisions to our outer mesh and use displacement.  Cycles only, and you must set your material displacement settings to either Displacement or Displacement and Bump.
Example 1
[image]

Example 2
[image]

Example 3, using undistorted texture coordinates
[image]

Comment: ... I don't want to tread on your very nice answer.. would it be possible to take it a little bit further still, by using the Voronoi, before threshold, as a displacement? To generate the little bumps on the surface? (OP refers to a 'model'). Ignore this, if it opens a can of worms....

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Could you just tell me what exactly are the "curved traits" ? Is that just a texture or a solid from blender ?

Comment: I'll add a couple things to this answer to make it more clear regarding both of your comments.